How to get Prolog to return false when user attempts to backtrack?
I want to make a program in Prolog that prints false when the user attempts to backtrack. This is my code:
likes(john, pizza).
likes(john, pasta).

% Predicate to track backtracking
:- dynamic(backtrack_attempted/0).

% Reset backtrack flag
reset_backtrack_flag :-
    retractall(backtrack_attempted).

% Set backtrack flag
set_backtrack_flag :-
    assert(backtrack_attempted).

likes_food(Person, Food) :-
    % Reset backtrack flag before each query
    reset_backtrack_flag,
    % Attempt to find a solution
    likes(Person, Food),
    % Set the backtrack flag after finding a solution
    set_backtrack_flag.

likes_food(_, _) :-
    % If backtracking is attempted, fail
    backtrack_attempted,
    !, fail.

% If no solution is found, fail
likes_food(_, _).

I'm hoping for this to happen:
?- likes(john, X).
X = pizza ;
false.

What actually keeps happening is this:
?- likes(john, X).
X = pizza ;
X = sushi.

Thanks in advance!

would ?- likes(john, X). 
X = pizza.  ?-  be satisfactory for you? if so, just end each clause of your predicate, like likes/2, with the  cut (!), like so: likes( _, _) :- !..

Relevant: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=det/1 and https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=once/1

You need to provide some rationale for this. The "user" does not backtrack, it is the Prolog itself that will backtrack. Now, do you want to only get the first solution? Or do you want to explicitly have some error if there is more than one solution? Or do you need a modified top level that fails if the user asks for more solutions?
